# Onclick calling funcion not working for one of my Divs

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am having a slight problem with my JS. I have a "how is works" template on my site, which when initiated, goes through steps how best to use my website.

Here is my code works fine for the `'showHelp()'` and `'next()'` functions, but doesnt work for the `'close()'` function.

```js
function showHelp() {
  document.getElementById('howItWorksBackground').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('howItWorks1').style.display = "block";
}
function next() {
  document.getElementById('howItWorks1').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('howItWorks2').style.display = "block";
}
function close() {
  document.getElementById('howItWorksBackground').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<button id="howItWorks" onclick='showHelp()'>How it works?</button> //This button initiates it 

<div id="howItWorksBackground" style="display: none;"> //This <div> is changed to "display: block" with the JS below
  <div id="howItWorks1" style="display: none;">
    <p id="text"> Some text...</p>
    <button id="next" onclick='next()'>Next</button>//upon clicking this, howItWorks2 
    is displayed and this block gets hidden
    <div id="whiteSpace"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="howItWorks2" style="display: none;">
    <p id="text">Some text.....</p>
    <button id="next" onclick='close()'>Close</button> //And when clicking here, the entire 
    "howItWorksBckground" should be hidden again, but my JS doesn't call it

    <div id="whiteSpace">
      <div id="insideText">
        Some text... 
        <br>
        Some text...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

This JS is really basic, but I can't figure out, why it isn't working...any help appreciated!

Comment: Rename your function to `closeIt` or something like that. (window.close already exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has already a **[`close()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/browsers.html#dom-window-close)** function (it's a reserved keyword) just rename your function and it will work.

**NOTE :** You should hide the div `howItWorks2` also in the close function.

Hope this helps.

```js
function showHelp() {
  document.getElementById('howItWorksBackground').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('howItWorks1').style.display = "block";
}
function next() {
  document.getElementById('howItWorks1').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('howItWorks2').style.display = "block";
}
function closeDiv() {
  document.getElementById('howItWorksBackground').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('howItWorks2').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<button id="howItWorks" onclick='showHelp()'>How it works?</button> //This button initiates it 

<div id="howItWorksBackground" style="display: none;"> //This <div> is changed to "display: block" with the JS below
  <div id="howItWorks1" style="display: none;">
    <p id="text"> Some text...</p>
    <button id="next" onclick='next()'>Next</button>//upon clicking this, howItWorks2 
    is displayed and this block gets hidden
    <div id="whiteSpace"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="howItWorks2" style="display: none;">
    <p id="text">Some text.....</p>
    <button id="next" onclick='closeDiv()'>Close</button>  //And when clicking here, the entire 
    "howItWorksBckground" should be hidden again, but my JS doesn't call it

    <div id="whiteSpace">
      <div id="insideText">
        Some text... 
        <br>
        Some text...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```